# element not clickable for radio options

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, radio-button

I am trying to find all elements by using `find_element_by_xpath`. In the below web elements, I am looking for these three elements separetely:

```
1.  <label for="hw-log-mode-none" class="ng-binding">None</label>
2.  <label for="hw-log-mode-session" class="ng-binding">Per-Session</label>
3.  <label for="hw-log-mode-mapping" class="ng-binding">Per-Mapping</label>

        <div class="field ng-scope" ng-if="!isTransparentMode &amp;&amp; showNatPool &amp;&amp; !policy.isIPv6" ng-show="policy.action == 'accept' &amp;&amp; policy.nat == 'enable'">
            <label class="ng-binding">Hardware Logging Mode</label>
            <div>
                <div class="radio-group">
                <input type="radio" id="hw-log-mode-none" value="none" ng-model="policy['hw-logging-mode']" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" name="670">
                    <label for="hw-log-mode-none" class="ng-binding">None</label>
                <input type="radio" id="hw-log-mode-session" value="session" ng-model="policy['hw-logging-mode']" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched" name="671" style="">
                    <label for="hw-log-mode-session" class="ng-binding">Per-Session</label>
                <input type="radio" id="hw-log-mode-mapping" value="mapping" ng-model="policy['hw-logging-mode']" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched ng-valid-parse" name="672" style="">
                    <label for="hw-log-mode-mapping" class="ng-binding">Per-Mapping</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I can find element **#1** and **#2** in above list. But when I try to find element **#3** using the same way:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@for='hw-log-mode-mapping']")
```

I got this error:

> Message: element click intercepted: Element ... is not
>   clickable at point (707, 508). Other element would receive the click:
>   ...   (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.90)

Comment: you will need to add dynamic wait until the element is clickable. Can you add the full stack trace

Comment: I dont know if a dynamic wait is the solution here. It's possible something with the layout on the page is blocking the element.

Comment: I add one line: time.sleep(1) before elem.click(). But still see this exception:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try clicking the element using Javascript and see if that works around the error.

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@for='hw-log-mode-mapping']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elem)
```

If that doesn't work, you could try clicking the `input` element itself.

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='hw-log-mode-mapping']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elem)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Get list of all the elements as they have same class name as follow:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//label[@class='ng-binding']"));
```

Now create a method to select the radio options as follow:

```
public void selectRadioOption(String option){
    if(option.equals("None"))
          elements.get(0).click();
    else if(option.equals("Per-Session"))
          elements.get(1).click();
    else if(option.equals("Per-Mapping"))
          elements.get(2).click();
}
```

Call this method, pass the option whichever you want to select.
Hope it works for you. You should not find 3 different xpath if you can work with one.